# Magnetism and magnetic fields

Tags: magnetic-fields

Why does a magnet attracts iron? Why does not the reverse case happens?

When a magnet attracts a metal, does it induce a current in it or does that happen only in the coil wound around a metal?

Comment: The reverse does happen. A force of attraction is an interaction between two objects. There isn't one object that is pulling the other object that is just along for the ride.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MO0r930Sn_8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reverse happens, also iron attracts magnet. It is also the consequence of [Newton's Third Law](https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/newtlaws/Lesson-4/Newton-s-Third-Law).

If the magnet is static (in the frame of the iron), then there is no induction. Magnetic field is created only by moving charges and affects only moving charges.